For every functional on $l_p$ it exists a sequence that determines it uniquely
I am trying to prove this excercise from my Functional analysis book:

Let $p \in (1, + \infty ) \subset \Bbb{R}$, $q = (1- \frac{1}{p})^{-1}$ and denote $l_p$ the space of $p-$bounded sequences of a field $\Bbb{K}$ $(\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C})$ . For every functional $f \in l_p ' $ it exists  a sequence $x = (x_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \in l_q$ such that $\lVert f \rVert = \lVert x \rVert_q $ and for every $y=(y_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \in l_p$ it has $f(y) = \sum_{k \in \Bbb{N}} x_k y_k $

My first thought was to denote for every $k \in \Bbb{N}: e_k = (0, \dots , 0 , 1^{(k)} , 0 , \dots )$ and take $x = ( f (e_k) )_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ . Since $f \in l'_p$ is linear and bounded, is continuous, so for every $y=(y_k)_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \in l_p$ we have $$ f(y) = f \left( \sum_ {k \in \Bbb{N}} y_k e_k \right) = f \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k e_k \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f \left( \sum_{k=1}^n y_k e_k \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n y_k f(e_k) = \sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}} y_k f(e_k)$$
The problem is that I do not have idea on how to prove that $x \in l_q$ and $\lVert f \rVert = \lVert x \rVert_q$ , so any possible help would be appreciated .
EDIT
By Hölder inequality I see that for every $y=(y_n) \in l_p : $
$$|f(y)| = | \sum_k x_k y_k | \leq \sum | x_k y_k | \leq \lVert x \rVert_q \cdot \lVert y \lVert_p $$
and therefore $\lVert f \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert_q$, so I would only need to prove $\lVert f \rVert \geq \lVert x \rVert_q$

Let's isolate the following. We have $$q=\bigl(1-\frac{1}{p}\bigr)^{-1}.\tag{I}$$
From this we deduce the following equivalent relations.
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1. \tag{II}$$
$$\frac{q}{p}+1=q.\tag{III}$$
$$\frac{q}{p}=q-1.\tag{IV}$$
Define $\epsilon:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be given byu $$\epsilon(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & : x = 0 \\ \frac{\overline{x}}{|x|} & : x \neq 0.\end{array}\right.$$ Note that $|\epsilon(x)|=1$ and $\epsilon(x)x=|x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$.
As stated in your solution, we have $f\in \ell_p'$ and $x_k=f(e_k)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We let $x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ and, as you showed with Holder, $x\in \ell_q$ and $\|x\|_q\geqslant \|f\|$.
For the reverse inequality, we note that $$\|x\|_q=\sup_n\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q\Bigr)^{1/q}.$$ So we only need to show that for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\|f\|\geqslant \Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q\Bigr)^{1/q}.$$  Since this holds for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it holds if we take the supremum over $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so the right side becomes $\|x\|_q$, and we're done.
Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $$c=\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q\Bigr)^{1/q}.$$ If $c=0$, then clearly $c\leqslant \|f\|$, so consider the case $c>0$. Define $$u=c^{-q/p}\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon(x_k)|x_k|^{q/p} e_k.$$ Then $$\|u\|_p^p=c^{-q}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{q}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q}{\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q}=1$$
and \begin{align*} f(u) & = c^{-q/p}\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon(x_k)|x_k|^{q/p}\cdot x_k = c^{-q/p}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{q/p+1} \\ & \overset{IV}{=} c^{-(q-1)}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{q/p+1} \\ & \overset{III}{=} c^{-(q-1)}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^q = \frac{c^q}{c^{q-1}}=c. \end{align*} Since $\|u\|_p=1$, $$\|f\|\geqslant |f(u)|=c.$$
Note that

Thank you for your answer!
